# ASP.Net - Issues with Repeater / DataBinding

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to bind my `labelIDs` in my application. I cannot get it to work. I'm sure sure if the name needs to match the name in the .cs file?

My code in the .aspx file:

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater_weatherReports" runat="server" onitemcommand="reptrData_ItemCommand">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table id="tblWeather" border="0" visible="true">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Weather Info
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCity_Country" Text='<%# Eval("city") %>' />&nbsp;
                        humidity:<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label_humidity" Text='<%# Eval("main.humidity") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        min:<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label_min" Text='<%# Eval("main.temp_min") %>' />
                        max:<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label_max" Text='<%# Eval("main.temp_max") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

My C# Code:

```
protected void reptrData_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Label lblCity = e.Item.FindControl("lblCity_Country") as Label;
    city_name = lblCity.Text;

    Label lblHumidity = e.Item.FindControl("Label_humidity") as Label;
    humidity = lblHumidity.Text;

    Label LblMin = e.Item.FindControl("Label_min") as Label;
    humidity = lblHumidity.Text;

    Label LblMax = e.Item.FindControl("Label_max") as Label;
    temp_max = lblHumidity.Text;


}



protected void GetWeatherInfo(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    string appID = "hidden";
    //string url = string.Format("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={0}&units=metric&cnt=2&APPID={1}",txtCity.Text,appID);

    string url = string.Format("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q={0},us&units=metric&cnt=5&APPID={1}", txtCity.Text, appID);




    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        string json = client.DownloadString(url);

        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        WeatherInfo weatherinfo = serializer.Deserialize<WeatherInfo>(json);

        Repeater_weatherReports.DataSource = weatherinfo.list;
        Repeater_weatherReports.DataBind();




        int i = 0;
        foreach (List list in weatherinfo.list)
        {





            city_name = weatherinfo.city.name;
            //lblDescription.Text = weatherinfo.list[0].weather[0].description;


            temp_min = string.Format("{0}", Math.Round(weatherinfo.list[i].main.temp_min, 1));
            temp_max = string.Format("{0}", Math.Round(weatherinfo.list[i].main.temp_max, 1));
            humidity = weatherinfo.list[i].main.humidity.ToString();
           // tblWeather.Visible = true;



            i++;
        }
}
```

The error message I am getting is

> 'An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in
>   System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: DataBinding: '_Default+List' does not contain a property
>   with the name 'city'.'

This is occurring on the line

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCity_Country" Text='<%# Eval("city") %>' />&nbsp;
```

I've not dealt with data binding / using the `Repeater` before. Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: The error-message is self-explanatory. Probably your `DataSource` has not a column named `City` for this part `Eval("city")`. It might be `main.city` or something else.

Comment: Hi S.Akbari, you're right I was missing the actual 'path' for city. I have added this is now. However I'm getting null values on these variable assignments:

                city_name = weatherinfo.list[i].main.city.name;
           


                temp_min = string.Format("{0}", Math.Round(weatherinfo.list[i].main.temp_min, 1));
                temp_max = string.Format("{0}", Math.Round(weatherinfo.list[i].main.temp_max, 1));

How would I call my 'reptrData_ItemCommand' method so that it can bind each label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like form the error that your Eval is not right.

```
 <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCity_Country" Text='<%# Eval("city") %>' />
```

You are binding the data with weatherinfo.list

```
     Repeater_weatherReports.DataSource = weatherinfo.list;
```

The list does not contain city property, but the weather info.

Comment: The city field is in my WeatherInfo Class

    public class WeatherInfo
    {
        public string cod { get; set; }
        public double message { get; set; }
        public int cnt { get; set; }
        public IList<List> list { get; set; }
        public City city { get; set; }
    }

So instead of binding the list of lists, I need to bound the parent class? Is that right?

Comment: You can create a protected variable and bind the td value with that. As it looks like for the whole table the city value will remain same. 
In case you have list of lists then better bind with the parent object.

Comment: I see thanks for the info,

One final issue I am encountering. The actual binding is not working. Must I pass through the variables 'city_name' etc  into my 'reptrData_ItemCommand' method?

Comment: Kindly post another question with your updated code. Need to see the code.